# moving a file that contains specific element to another directory python

Tags: python, elementtree

I have the following code that prints the element I need in all xml files i have in the directory, im trying to move the files that contains the element "drone" to another directory but i cant make it, maybe someone can help me with that?

```
import os
import shutil
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
# files are in a sub folder where this script is being ran
path = "D:\\TomProject\\Done"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    # Only get xml files
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    # I haven't been able to get it to work by just saying 'if filename.endswith('.xml')' only 
if not..
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    # This joins the path for each file it files so that python knows the full path / filename 
to trigger parser
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    # Parse the files..
    print(filename)
    # Get the root of the XML tree structure
    root = tree.getroot()
    # Print the tags it finds from all the child elements from root
    for object in root.findall('object'):
     rank = object.find('name').text
     print(rank)
     name = 'drone'
     if rank == 'Drone':
         shutil.move("D:\\TomProject\\Images", "D:\\TomProject\\Done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code appears to be calling [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) with 2 hard-coded paths, but you should be passing the full path (`fullname` in your code) as the `src` argument instead.

I recommend using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os.path` functions.

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def contains_drone(path):
    tree = ET.parse(path.as_posix())
    root = tree.getroot()
    for obj in root.findall('object'):
        rank = obj.find('name').text
        if rank == 'Drone':
            return True
    return False


def move_drone_files(src, dst):
    src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
    for path in src.iterdir():
        if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
            print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
            shutil.move(path, dst)
```

Usage, assuming the `Images` directory is where the files are, and the `Done` directory is where you want to move them:

```py
move_drone_files('D:\\TomProject\\Images', 'D:\\TomProject\\Done')
```

Comment: just to be clear, the code you just posted should replace the one i have?

Comment: Yes; the logic for determining whether the file contains `drone` was split out into a separate function to make it easier to handle that portion of the logic.  The `src.iterdir()` loop is equivalent to the `os.listdir(...)` one.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i cant find where i need to fill my directory path

Comment: The last line of my answer provides an example of how you would call it - if the paths are incorrect in my example, then you should replace them with the actual ones.

Comment: the paths are correct but when i put the paths it says "invalid parameter"

Comment: To test, I made a directory with `Images` and `Done` subdirectories.  In Images, I had 3 files - `foo.txt`, `bar.xml` containing a match, and `baz.xml` containing a different name.  I started an `ipython` interactive session, and pasted the code from the answer.  I then called `move_drone_files` with the 2 test paths, and it worked as expected.  I would need more context for how/why it would end up saying `invalid parameter` to suggest anything.  Are you using at least Python 3.7 or above?

Comment: i have python 3.7 or above, the problem i have now is that when i copy the path as you said i have red line under the two paths and is colored grey.

Comment: At last i got the code working perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: I have another question for you, now that it moves the xml file i would like to move another txt and jpeg file that have the exact name as the xml file, how can i do that?

Comment: I would suggest trying to apply what you saw here to that case, and if you still can't figure it out, then it should be a separate question.